# classFactory() method ImportError:

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am developing a qgis plugin. In eclipse pydev. The plugin has been designed with the "plugin builder" plugin since it's recomended.
  So I have designed a few classes that I wanted to do the heavy lifting. And put them in source folders. As follows:
[image: The FOO plugin]

So everything is runing smothly in my IDE and it looks like this:

```
from Ang import  Ang #Ang as in anxiety

print Ang('fooo BAR') # Ang simply returns the same string
```

Output in IDE:

```
fooo BAR
```

But when i use the "Reload plugin" plugin I get this error message :
    Kunde inte ladda insticksprogram FOO på grund av ett fel med classFactory() metoden

```
ImportError: No module named Ang 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 306, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/Vilya/.qgis2/python/plugins\FOO\__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
    from .FOO import FOO
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/Vilya/.qgis2/python/plugins\FOO\FOO.py", line 23, in 
    from Foo_package import bar
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/Vilya/.qgis2/python/plugins\FOO\Foo_package\bar.py", line 10, in 
    from Ang import  Ang
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named Ang


Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.14.12-Essen Essen, d8da919 

Python sökväg:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/Vilya/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/Vilya/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin\ C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\apps\qgis-ltr\python
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin\ C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/Vilya/.qgis2//python
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins\fTools\tools
```

Sorry for the extremly long error message (it's in swedish since Qgis auto translates all strings and I use a Swedish computer).
All FOO classes are the generated stubs. So what does this extremly long error code mean? And what can i Do to rectify it?

I think it has somthing to do whith how classfactory is setup.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with two quick-fixes for solving the error. Both allows the plugin to run. But neither usese a source package thus the organization of the code becomes less neat.

Solution one (the one i use):
Simply move the class modules upp a level directly in the plugin project folder.

[image: Solution_one]

The second soluttion was to simply write it into the FOO.py class.

```
class Ang(object):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''


    def __new__ (cls, s):
        return s

class FOO:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.
```

Both removes the error neither pleases me as an answer. I still don't know the exakt nature of my errors.